# Dynamically Casting In ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

Is there a way to cast dynamically in Actionscript?  What I want to accomplish is illustrated by the following code:

```
        var Val:*;
        var S:String=SomeTextEdit.text;
        switch (DesiredTypeTextEdit.text) {
          case 'int':Val=int(S);break; 
          case 'uint':Val=uint(S);break; 
          case 'String':Val=String(S);break; 
          case 'Number':Val=Number(S);break; 
          ...
        }
        SomeDisplayObject[SomePropertyNameTextEdit.text]=Val;
```

I am looking for something LIKE the following PSEUDOCODE:

```
SomeDisplayObject[SomePropertyName]=eval(DesiredType)(SomeTextEdit.text);
```

Yes, I already realize that "eval" is not on the table, nor is that how one would use it.

What's the RIGHT way?

Comment: This question has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016201/dynamic-object-initiation-as3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

http://benrimbey.wordpress.com/2009/06/20/reflection-based-json-validation-with-vo-structs/

Check the "mapToFlexObjects" function. He's basically reading from text and assigning classes at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to play the try-catch game, but googling some of these flash.utils would hopefully be a means to your end:

```
getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(variable))
```

You'll probably have to import all of the different 'types' you intend on using into the project somewhere, but this should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Not too sure on exactly what you after (your example is a little confusing), but I will try and answer.

You can type-cast a variable only when you create a variable. You can do one of the following to change the type of a variable, but you must create a new variable of the new type.

```
var foo:Number = 230;
var foo2:int = foo as int;
```

or

```
var foo:Number = 230;
var foo2:int = int(foo);
```

If you use the asterisks (*) as your variable type, then what ever you set the variable to, it will become that type. Try this as a test:

```
var foo:* = new Sprite();
trace(foo); // Traces: "[object Sprite]"
```

This is somewhat bad practice, and bad software design. But sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do!
[How bad is dynamic casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080/how-bad-is-dynamic-casting)

Comment: This doesn't tell me anything at all about how to cast it dynamically ie: When the destination type of the cast is only known at runtime.

Comment: If you are casting dynamically, the type will only be known at runtime anyway!?! That is basically the definition of "dynamic casting"